# bash_profile for new user created through useradd

Tags: path, bash, user-administration

I created a new user in RHEL7

```
useradd newuser
```

When I opened the ~/.bash_profile of this user, the output is

```
 $cat -n ~/.bash_profile
 1  # .bash_profile
 2
 3  # Get the aliases and functions
 4  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
 5      . ~/.bashrc
 6   fi
 7    
 8  # User specific environment and startup programs
 9    
 10  PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
 11
 12  export PATH
 $
```

From where this `bash_profile` is inherited to the newly added user?
If I need to removing appending of `$PATH` for the every new user created using `useradd`. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `/etc/skel` (or `SKEL_DIR` from `-k`) as explained in the man page for the `-m/--create-home` option most likely.

If you don't want that then don't have `useradd` create the home directory and/or just delete the file after the user is created.

Comment: But I need the home directory created for every user. Skeleton directory looks fine. Thanks :-)

Comment: You can create the directory yourself without needing `useradd` to do it for you but you can also just control the skeleton directory if that suits your purpose better.